# Where does the HTML spec state that a <template>'s contents are inert?

Tags: javascript, html, html5-template

[The `template` element is used to declare fragments of HTML that can be cloned and inserted in the document by script.](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/scripting.html#the-template-element) The "contents of the `template`" (as accessed via `HTMLTemplateElement.prototype.content`) are stored in a `DocumentFragment` associated with a different `Document` other than the main `document`.

So, because `templ.content.ownerDocument != document`, this is OK:

```
<template id="templ">
  <script>console.error('This does not execute!');</script>
</template>
```

`templ.content` is an inert `DocumentFragment`, that's fine.

---

**Edit: The rest of the question, below, has an incorrect premise -- I was testing this by creating a template in JavaScript with `document.createElement` instead of via HTML, which yields different results.** More precisely, when creating a template and using `document.body.appendChild`, the template is adopted into `document` which [specifically adopts `template.content` into `document`](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/scripting.html#template-adopting-steps).

> However, the `template` itself, *and* its descendants, *are*
>   associated with `document`:
>
> ```
> templ.children[0].tagName == 'script'
> templ.children[0].ownerDocument == document
> ```
>
> In other words, the `script` is still a part of the main `Document`,
>   which would normally mean it executes.
>
> While the spec explains the `DocumentFragment` accessed via
>   `.content`, that doesn't account for this concrete, instantiated
>   `<script>` instance having its associated `Document` be the main
>   `document` but not executing.
>
> Does the spec explain somewhere exactly why this `<script>` isn't
>   executed? How is it excluded from execution if it does belong to
>   `document`?
>
> ---
>
> (I realize it's useful for the script not to execute. This is a
>   question about the spec, not about the usefulness of `<template>` or
>   whether the in-browser behavior is appropriate.)

Comment: http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/scripting-1.html#the-template-element mentions inert in multiple places talks about how it lives as a different document.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, there's [this note](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/scripting-1.html#the-template-element) on the `template` element description:

> **Note:** Templates provide a method for declaring **inert** DOM subtrees and manipulating them to instantiate document fragments with identical contents.

*(My emphasis.)* It then goes into it in a fair bit of detail in the following paragraphs *(my emphasis)*:

> A Document doc's appropriate template contents owner document is the Document returned by the following algorithm:
>
> 1. If doc is not a Document created by this algorithm, run these substeps:
>
>    1. If doc does not yet have an associated **inert** template document then run these substeps:
>
>       1. Let new doc be a new Document (that does not have a browsing context). This is "a Document created by this algorithm" for the purposes of the step above.
>       2. If doc is an HTML document, mark new doc as an HTML document also.
>       3. Let doc's associated **inert** template document be new doc.
>    2. Set doc to doc's associated **inert** template document.
> 2. Return doc

Comment: This is probably as close to an answer as my question allowed. The assertion I was making about `templ.children` was actually incorrect, because my question used a template created in HTML, but I was actually [creating the template in JS to test it out, which *does* run the script](https://jsfiddle.net/mgiuffrida/o6gLc6dy/)

Comment: if you are creating in JS, why not just use a document fragment

Comment: @chiliNUT: right. I was only using JS to test my understanding of the element's behavior. And didn't realize that behavior differed when it was created dynamically.